# MessagesInPerSec for all topics metrics for Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Can someone help me here understanding this particular kafka broker metrics for monitoring. I have tried reading the documentation and some articles but i am unclear on this metrics on how this needs to be monitored to avoid any harm to the kafka brokers in the prod environment. I see spikes reaching numbers in 5k per second in my prod environment for this metrics but then it comes back to 2k per second or even less.

Same goes for the bytes per messaging.

Any detailed explaination will be very helpful

Comment: Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered.

Answer (score 1):

When you have any troubles with performance you shall focus on metrics (JMX) which are providing information like bytes per sec per topic "in" and "out".
The metric you mention or rather generic and says not too much.

We encountered in our tests, that Kafka has concrete maximum in throughput and it depends from the message size. So when we had send 1MB messages in out network we had like 170MB/s transfer, but by sending 10MB messages we got 150MB/s. So the important is not the only number of messages, but also the size.

And to measure Kafka, you can use whatever that will read and understand JMX.
And using it, we did not had any significant performance problems.

Very detailed documentation about Kafka JMX attributes: [Monitoring Kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. We have the JMX metrics enabled for the BytesInPerSec and has the attribute 'Count' which is continuously increasing. I am not clear on the understanding of this attribute. As per my view, this number will be collecting the count since the broker was started.We added some threshold values but it's crossing the same all the time. Should I concentrate more on Per 5 min metrics. Anyone using this metrics?

Comment: Go to the Monitoring Kafka page (link in my answer) and check, which metric fits your need the best :-).